# How to discover which classes were loaded when requiring a Ruby file

Tags: ruby

If I require a Ruby file that contains class definitions, how can I discover what classes were added by the require without having to view the contents of the file?

For example, if I have file 'foobar.rb', consisting only of the following:

```
class Foo
end

class Bar
end
```

I know that if I require this file, I now have Foo and Bar available:

```
>> require 'foobar' #=> true
>> Foo #=> Foo
>> Bar #=> Bar
```

Supposing I didn't know what the contents of foobar.rb were and I merely required it.  How would I discover that Foo and Bar are now new class constants?

Comment: If your code can discover a class was added, which isn't hard, it's still not going to know what to do with the newly added classes. You, as the developer, are still going to have to integrate that into your application. The day an app can sense a new class, and automatically know how to use it, is the day that all programmers using that language will become obsolete.

Comment: You accepted an answer a mere 17 minutes after posting the question.  What's the hurry?  In general, rushing to a decision discourages more (possibly better) answers, and it's not respectful to those who are still working on answers, who are not expecting an answer to be chosen mere minutes after it has been asked. I expect Sergio and Arup were probably working on their answers when the green checkmark flashed on.

Comment: Hi, sorry first time asking a question on SO.  What's the commonly agreed upon courtesy time to wait before accepting a question?

Comment: @the Tin Man.  An app that can sense a new class and automatically know how to use it is not as exotic as it sounds, in fact you do it all the time.

Comment: That's my point. *I* do it; My code has no clue. Once the language and code has evolved to the point that code can discover and understand the syntax for calling newly discovered classes, and wire them in to use the results of that class, then programmers will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in classes and modules which are defined at the top level, i.e. not inside a Module, you can do it like this:

```
previously_defined = Object.constants
require 'foobar'
just_defined = Object.constants - previously_defined
```

(You'll have to filter out the names of modules if you don't want them.)

If you need to get *all* classes, you can do:

```
previously_defined = []
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) { |cls| previously_defined << cls }
require 'foobar'
just_defined = []
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) { |cls| just_defined << cls }
just_defined -= previously_defined
```

Comment: Very nice although `to_a` would be sufficient i.e. `previously_defined = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a` and `just_defined = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a - previously_defined`

Comment: If you've tried that, and it works, go ahead and edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using a *hacky* approach. Each time when you will be defining a new custom class using `class` keyword, or [`Class::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Class.html#method-c-new), whatever, a hook method [`Class#inherited`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Class.html#method-i-inherited) method called always.

Thus, put the below code in your file :

```
class Object
  def self.inherited(subclass)
   (@classes ||= []) << subclass
  end
  def self.display_all_loaded_custom_class
    @classes
  end
end

class Foo;end
class Bar;end

self.class.display_all_loaded_custom_class # => [Foo, Bar]
```

Whenever you will be defining any class, without making it a subclass of any other class, `Object` becomes the default *superclass* of these class(s). Thus it is very expected you need to define `Object::inherited` method to track those.

Answer (score 2):

Using system tracer:

```
# one.rb
class Foo
end

class Bar
end

# two.rb
require 'tracer'

Tracer.add_filter {|event| event == 'class' }

Tracer.on {
  require './one'
}

>> #0:/Users/sergio/projects/tmp/mp/one.rb:1::C: class Foo
>> #0:/Users/sergio/projects/tmp/mp/one.rb:4::C: class Bar
```

Documentation: [Tracer](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/tracer/rdoc/Tracer.html#method-c-on).

Comment: He he.. Good use of `tracer`... +1

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
classes = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a
require 'foobar'
new_classes = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a - classes
```

This will only return newly defined classes instead of all the defined constants.